# Axios не может расспарсить JSON

Tags: javascript, php, axios

Работаю на VueJs с подключением Axios. Не расспарсивает пришедшую с сервера JSON.
Формирую JSON строку на PHP из массива с помощью:

```
$response['status'] = null;
$response['status'] = "Error";
echo json_encode($response);
```

Код JS

```
axios({
                method: 'POST',
                headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' },
                url: '../modules/autorisation.php',
                data: {
                    login: this.login,
                    password: this.password
                }
            })
            .then(function(response){
                console.log(response['data']);
                // console.log(JSON.parse(response['data']));

            })
            .catch(function(error){
                console.log(error);
            });
```

Выводит JSON строку ( ﻿{"status":"Error"} ), хотя обычно Axios обычно распарсивает всё самостоятельно.
Если пытаюсь расспарсить в ручную, то появляется ошибка, что в json строке ошибка  в первом символе.

Comment: А правильный content-type из php пробовали отдать?

Comment: На сервер информация приходит в нормальном виде и обрабатывается как положено. Проблема в ответе сервера,если в ручную попробовать расспарсить, то появляется ошибка: "SyntaxError: Unexpected token  in JSON at position 0
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
    at autorisation.js:41" хотя пришедшая json не имеет ошибок.

Comment: Клиенту приходит json, но он почему то парсится: https://yadi.sk/i/SJzLA0oSqGkjoQ

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте явно указать тип возвращаемого контента через HTTP заголовок `Content-Type`:

```
$response['status'] = "Error";
header('Content-Type: application/json');
echo json_encode($response);
```

И указать тип принимаемых данных на стороне клиента с помощью параметра `responseType`:

```
axios({
    method: 'POST',
    headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' },
    url: '../modules/autorisation.php',
    data: {
        login: this.login,
        password: this.password
    },
    responseType: 'json'
})
```

Comment: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at W:\OpenServer\OSPanel\domains\sportshop\modules\db_connect.php:1) in <b>W:\OpenServer\OSPanel\domains\sportshop\modules\autorisation.php</b> on line <b>27</b><br />

Comment: О, вангную BOM в начале файла

Comment: Всё файлы в UTF-8 без BOM, и vue js скрипт,и php обработчик

Comment: https://yadi.sk/i/SJzLA0oSqGkjoQ Content-Type выводит json

Comment: Дополнил ответ. можно еще попробовать `responseType` указать. Но прежде всего нужно убедиться, что сервер отдает валидный JSON. Никаких `headers already sent` или другого лишнего текста или символов в ответе не должно быть.

Comment: @КонстантинСтрамаус проверьте таки файл db_connect.php из сообщения выше